# How to achieve the association of file and memory in K8S?

Tags: kubernetes

In k8s, we can use the `memory` medium(`tmpfs` instance) to define the `emptyDir` volume and mount it to pod's container. In the container, we can read and write data according to the `file` interface.

I want to know how does k8s achieve the association of `file` and `memory`? What is the principle of reading and writing `memory` data as `file`? `mmap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wikipdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs):

> tmpfs is a temporary file storage paradigm **implemented in many Unix-like operating systems**. It is intended to appear as a mounted file system, but data is stored in volatile memory instead of a persistent storage device. A similar construction is a RAM disk, which appears as a virtual disk drive and hosts a disk file system.

So its not k8s feature. Is is a Linux feature that just appears to be used by k8s.

You can read more about it in [linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)